# Passing res id to Android Adapters

Tags: android, adapter

If I use adapters (ArrayAdapter, SimpleAdapter, SimpleCursorAdapter) I always need to pass res id of the layout which will be used for each item. I need to know everything in design time and what if that is not the case. I only know at runtime that I need five TextViews on one layout and I'd like to dinamically create such layout and pass that to adapter. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible to create a `View` hierarchy programatically. You can refer to creating [Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) to know about some of the methods.

Comment: If so, I know how to create new instance of a view dinamically but what do you pass to adapter in such case?

Comment: The Adapters that you have mentioned are provided for convenience. You can always extend the `BaseAdapter` and create your own implementation. Moreover, from `ArrayAdapter` documentation: "_To use something other than TextViews for the array display, for instance, ImageViews, or to have some of data besides toString() results fill the views, override getView(int, View, ViewGroup) to return the type of view you want._". In the latter case, you can pass any value (which is not anyway used) in the resourceId parameter.